# camera problem in iphone sdk

Tags: xcode, ios4, camera

i would like to open camera in my tab bar app..
i have open the camera but i could not taken the picture because i didnt find the camera symbol in that screen so please tell me how i can i show the camera button(for capture) in camera view? i am also tested it in my iPhone. camera opened but i could not find any button to pick the image.. how can i got if?
Thank You..
code is

```
picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

picker.delegate = self;

picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

[Delegate presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
       [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

instead of

```
  [Delegate presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```